# Why two probability density function equals each other when one is multiplied by the absolute value of the ration of their differentials?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given two distinct probability density functions $p_{s}(S)$ and $p_{r}(R)$ they can be correlated with this formula:

$$p_{s}(S) = p_{r}(R)\lvert\frac{dr}{ds}\rvert$$

Why?

This formula is particularly important in computer vision but everyone gives for granted that you know why it works and what it really means.

Also, does it have a name? When was it discovered and by who?

Comment: On the elementary level, this is just the change of variable in calculus. The $\left\lvert \frac{dr}{ds} \right\rvert$ is the absolute value of the Jacobian. In the measure-theoretic treatment, this is the Radon-Nikodym derivative.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more, maybe as an answer? Unfortunately I am not that familiar with probability math.